# Applying CSS parameters based on scroll position with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

In the example below, I have two invisible buttons that fill the whole page. The `button` in the second half horizontally scrolls to the next `section`, and the `button` on left to the previous `section`.

```js
const createButton = () => document.createElement("button")
const insertButton = button => {
  document.body.append(button)
  return button
}

const [goToPreviousSection, goToNextSection] = [
  createButton(),
  createButton()
].map(insertButton)

goToPreviousSection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollBy(-window.innerWidth, 0)
})

goToNextSection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollBy(window.innerWidth, 0)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html,
body,
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 {
  color: white
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none
}

button:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0;
  cursor: w-resize
}
button:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
  cursor: e-resize
}
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```

How can I set the `width` of the second `button` to be `100%` and `z-index` to `1` when it's at `0` page scroll position on the left, and same for the width of the first `button` when it's scrolled to the end of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that works by toggling a class on both buttons to show them fullscreen when we reach one side or the other. It is important to increase the z-index of the fullscreen button since the left button is rendered before the next button.

```js
const createButton = () => document.createElement("button")
const insertButton = button => {
  document.body.append(button)
  return button
}

const [goToPreviousSection, goToNextSection] = [
  createButton(),
  createButton()
].map(insertButton)

const previousButtonFullscreen = () => {
  goToNextSection.classList.remove("fullscreen")
  goToPreviousSection.classList.add("fullscreen")
}

const nextButtonFullscreen = () => {
  goToPreviousSection.classList.remove("fullscreen")
  goToNextSection.classList.add("fullscreen")
}

const noButtonFullscreen = () => {
  goToPreviousSection.classList.remove("fullscreen")
  goToNextSection.classList.remove("fullscreen")
}

const updateButtons = () => {
  if (window.scrollX === 0) {
    nextButtonFullscreen()
  } else if (document.body.scrollWidth - window.scrollX === window.innerWidth) {
    previousButtonFullscreen()
  } else {
    noButtonFullscreen()
  }
}

goToPreviousSection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollBy(-window.innerWidth, 0)
  updateButtons();
})

goToNextSection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollBy(window.innerWidth, 0)
  updateButtons()
})

updateButtons()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html,
body,
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 {
  color: white
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none
}

button:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0;
  cursor: w-resize
}
button:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
  cursor: e-resize
}

.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```